# undefined method '_path' with references

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, reference

I'm looking for make draw lesson with a differente gallery link with each lessons for the users can uplaod there work in.

I have a controller, model and view named "lesson" and the linked gallery is "illst_repot"
I have linked the illust_repot with references.
lesson:references and user:references

I have no problem on the index page, but I have a problem on new page
undefined method `illust_reports_path'
localhost:3000/lessons/1/illust_reports/new

This is my routes

```
lesson_illust_reports GET        /lessons/:lesson_id/illust_reports(.:format)             illust_reports#index
                                              POST       /lessons/:lesson_id/illust_reports(.:format)             illust_reports#create
                     new_lesson_illust_report GET        /lessons/:lesson_id/illust_reports/new(.:format)         illust_reports#new
                    edit_lesson_illust_report GET        /lessons/:lesson_id/illust_reports/:id/edit(.:format)    illust_reports#edit
                         lesson_illust_report GET        /lessons/:lesson_id/illust_reports/:id(.:format)         illust_reports#show
                                              PATCH      /lessons/:lesson_id/illust_reports/:id(.:format)         illust_reports#update
                                              PUT        /lessons/:lesson_id/illust_reports/:id(.:format)         illust_reports#update
                                              DELETE     /lessons/:lesson_id/illust_reports/:id(.:format)         illust_reports#destroy
                                      lessons GET        /lessons(.:format)                                       lessons#index
                                              POST       /lessons(.:format)                                       lessons#create
                                   new_lesson GET        /lessons/new(.:format)                                   lessons#new
                                  edit_lesson GET        /lessons/:id/edit(.:format)                              lessons#edit
                                       lesson GET        /lessons/:id(.:format)                                   lessons#show
                                              PATCH      /lessons/:id(.:format)                                   lessons#update
                                              PUT        /lessons/:id(.:format)                                   lessons#update
                                              DELETE     /lessons/:id(.:format)                                   lessons#destroy
```

## routes.rb

```
  resources :lessons do
    resources :illust_reports
  end
```

## illust_reports_controller.rb

```
class IllustReportsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_illust_report, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :illust_report_owner, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /illust_reports
  # GET /illust_reports.json
  def index
    @illust_reports = IllustReport.all
  end

  def illust_report_owner
    unless @illust_report.user_id == current_user.id
    flash[:notice] = "Accès refusé car tu n'es pas l'auteur de ce billet."
    redirect_to illust_reports_path
    end
  end

  # GET /illust_reports/1
  # GET /illust_reports/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /illust_reports/new
  def new
    @illust_report = current_user.illust_reports.build
  end

  # GET /illust_reports/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /illust_reports
  # POST /illust_reports.json
  def create
    @illust_report = current_user.illust_reports.build(illust_report_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @illust_report.save
        format.html { redirect_to @illust_report, notice: 'Illust report was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @illust_report }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @illust_report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /illust_reports/1
  # PATCH/PUT /illust_reports/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @illust_report.update(illust_report_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @illust_report, notice: 'Illust report was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @illust_report }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @illust_report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /illust_reports/1
  # DELETE /illust_reports/1.json
  def destroy
    @illust_report.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to illust_reports_url, notice: 'Illust report was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_illust_report
      @illust_report = IllustReport.find_by(id: params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def illust_report_params
      params.require(:illust_report).permit(:title, :image, :commentaire, :lesson_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

## _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@illust_report) do |f| %>
  <% if @illust_report.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@illust_report.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this illust_report from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @illust_report.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

The model are linked.
I'm beginner with rails, I have searched a long time on google, and stack, and make many test before write this message.
Where is the problem ?
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: When you get that error? On landing on new page or when you submit the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> undefined method `illust_reports_path'

You have ***nested resources***. So the `form_for` should look like below

```
<%= form_for [@lesson, @illust_report] do |f| %>
```

and change the `illust_reports_controller`'s `new` method like below

```
def new
  @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:lesson_id])
  @illust_report = current_user.illust_reports.build
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It work. Now, I have a last promblem. I want to show the illust_reports post only on his personnal index. The page http://localhost:3000/lessons/1/illust_reports show all illus_reports of all lessons. Same for the http://localhost:3000/lessons/2/illust_reports index. How I can show only the illus_reports of the lesson 1 on the http://localhost:3000/lessons/1/illust_reports page and same for the lessons 2 ? Thank you

Comment: It's Ok, I have type this @illust_reports = IllustReport.where(:lesson_id => params[:lesson_id]).order("created_at DESC")

Answer (score 0):

Does `lesson_illust_reports_path` work?

As your `illust_report` resource is namespaced inside your `lessons` resource, you have to prepend `lesson`.

Comment: Thank you. No, the 'lessons_illust_reports_path' doesn't work. No route matches [GET] "/lessons_illust_reports_path". Where I need to prepend lessons. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, please have another look @Jean-Baptiste: I corrected my answer to `lesson_illust_reports_path` (lesson without s). You always have to prepend lesson to `illust_report`, as lesson is the outer resource.

Comment: It doesn't work. Sorry I don't understand. I have created lesson 1 localhost:3000/lessons/1/ It's work. Next http://localhost:3000/lessons/1/illust_reports link work but this http://localhost:3000/lessons/1/illust_reports/new don't work.  undefined method `illust_reports_path' ... <%= form_for(@illust_report) do |f| %> is red